# How is the big bang a plausible theory?

Tags: big-bang-theory, matter

In the Big Bang Theory, it is said that it started with a small speck of matter, yet we have an unimaginable mass of expanding universe which is assumed as immeasurable. If the theory of "Matter cannot be created nor destroyed" than how is it possible for the Big Bang to be considered true?

What is not correct about my (very amateur) understanding?

Comment: Also see [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/123208)

Comment: The "big bang" is a model, not a theory. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187967/what-is-the-difference-between-a-model-and-a-theory